# UItableView scroll with lag after update to xcode 7 and use iOS 9 even in simple cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9, xcode7

After i updated XCode to 7.0 version
all my `UITableViews` view with loading image using `SDWebImage` component scroll with lag
This is my `cellForRow` method
and when i delete line codes with loading image it scroll much faster and smooth

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


MatchTodayCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"matchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

MatchTodayObject *obj =  [[self.matchesArr  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.hostLabel.text = obj.hostTeam;
cell.guestLabel.text = obj.guestTeam;
cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",  [self checkDate:obj.date],obj.time ];

[cell.hostImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.hostLogo] placeholderImage:IMG(@"teamlogoplaceholder")];
[cell.guestImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.guestLogo] placeholderImage:IMG(@"teamlogoplaceholder")];

cell.notificationButton.tag = obj.ID ;

if ([self.matchIdsWithNotification containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: obj.ID ]]) {

    [cell.notificationButton setImage:IMG(@"NotificationsActivated") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.notificationButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}
else
{
    [cell.notificationButton setImage:IMG(@"NotificationsnotActivated") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.notificationButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
cell.hostPointLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", obj.hostPoint ];
cell.guesPointlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",  obj.guestPoint ] ;

if (obj.isFinished) {

    cell.stateImg.image = IMG(@"endedtag");
    cell.notificationButton.enabled  = NO;

}
else
{
    if (obj.isStarted) {
        cell.stateImg.image = IMG(@"livetag");

        cell.notificationButton.enabled  = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.stateImg.image = IMG(@"Soontag");
        cell.notificationButton.enabled  = YES;

    }

}

return cell;

    }
```